# Efficiently comparing vectors within a list and removing highly similar elements while considering element positions

Tags: r

I'm currently working on a task that involves comparing vectors within a list in R and removing those that exhibit a similarity of 60% or higher with other vectors.

However, I want to emphasize that in this comparison, the similarity of elements alone is not the sole criterion; the positions of elements within each vector also play a crucial role.
Furthermore the vectors can be of different lengths.

I have made some progress on this task but would greatly appreciate some guidance on how to optimize the process for efficiency and consider the position of the elements. Here's the code I have so far. (This code has several mistakes in it):

```
removeSimilarVectors <- function(vectorList) {
  # Determine the maximum length of vectors in the list
  maxLen <- max(lengths(vectorList))
  
  # Pad shorter vectors with NA to make them equal in length
  paddedVectors <- lapply(vectorList, function(x) {
    if (length(x) < maxLen) c(x, rep(NA, maxLen - length(x)))
    else x
  })
  
  # Convert list of vectors to a numeric matrix
  matrixData <- do.call(cbind, paddedVectors)
  
  # Compute the pairwise distances between all vectors
  distances <- dist(t(matrixData))
  
  # Compute the maximum possible distance between vectors
  maxDistance <- sqrt(maxLen)
  
  # Create a logical matrix indicating vectors that are more than 60% similar
  similarMatrix <- as.matrix(distances) <= (0.6 * maxDistance)
  
  # Find the indices of vectors that are more than 60% similar to another vector
  similarIndices <- apply(similarMatrix, 1, function(x) any(x[-which(x)]))
  
  # Return the list of vectors without the similar ones
  vectorList[!similarIndices]
}
```

Example Data:

```
list_of_vectors<-list(c(613L, 1969L, 1981L, 1980L, 1976L, 1972L, 619L, 617L, 620L, 
584L, 585L, 572L, 571L, 570L, 1108L, 1110L, 1114L, 1115L, 1116L, 
1117L, 1132L, 1135L, 1133L, 1134L, 1142L, 1272L, 1273L, 1248L, 
1249L, 1247L, 1250L, 1241L, 1240L, 1213L, 1214L, 1212L, 1211L, 
1210L, 1208L, 1205L, 1207L, 1218L, 1224L, 2480L, 1223L, 1220L, 
2258L, 2261L, 2260L, 2259L, 2257L, 906L, 905L, 909L, 910L, 953L, 
912L, 949L, 948L, 938L, 916L, 921L, 974L, 972L, 967L, 983L, 965L, 
958L, 960L, 961L, 962L, 964L, 525L, 527L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 499L, 
503L, 523L, 513L, 392L, 393L, 387L, 1821L, 1820L, 1809L, 1808L, 
1806L, 1805L, 1804L, 321L, 326L, 329L, 1789L, 1788L, 1787L, 1791L, 
1790L, 1792L, 1793L, 341L, 340L, 338L, 344L, 343L, 342L, 311L, 
689L, 690L, 685L, 684L, 683L, 682L, 680L, 681L, 679L, 678L, 677L, 
676L, 668L, 671L, 673L, 674L, 661L, 662L, 666L, 658L, 659L, 656L, 
655L, 654L, 653L, 652L, 1054L, 1055L, 1056L, 1057L, 1059L, 2323L, 
2327L, 1063L, 2326L, 1064L, 1065L, 1072L, 1071L, 2333L, 2340L, 
2315L, 1002L, 1003L, 2266L), c(610L, 612L, 614L, 1962L, 607L, 
633L, 632L, 631L, 1988L, 1990L, 1994L, 1997L, 2001L, 87L, 1580L, 
1579L, 1581L, 1582L, 1585L, 1586L, 1583L, 1584L, 2000L, 1998L, 
1617L, 1620L, 1629L, 1626L, 1628L, 1630L, 1631L, 146L, 1633L, 
1632L, 1642L, 2718L, 2717L, 2363L, 2393L, 2392L, 2394L, 2390L, 
2389L, 2262L, 2184L, 2190L, 2189L, 2188L, 2191L, 2192L, 2187L, 
2186L, 2185L, 2182L, 2181L, 2180L, 2183L, 2208L, 2209L, 2200L, 
2201L, 2202L, 2199L, 2240L, 2241L, 2252L, 2251L, 2243L, 2244L, 
2249L, 2245L, 2246L, 2247L, 2248L, 2236L, 2235L, 2234L, 2233L, 
2232L, 942L, 932L, 926L, 927L, 928L, 945L, 2237L, 2238L, 941L, 
939L, 937L, 916L, 921L, 974L, 972L, 967L, 983L, 965L, 958L, 960L, 
961L, 962L, 964L, 525L, 527L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 493L, 490L, 482L, 
480L, 479L, 1877L, 1878L, 1879L, 1880L, 1876L, 1874L, 1863L, 
1862L, 438L, 471L, 468L, 469L, 1884L, 1883L, 472L, 473L, 812L, 
811L, 796L, 797L, 804L, 805L, 808L, 798L, 799L, 793L, 2141L, 
2151L, 817L, 818L, 819L, 737L, 738L, 742L, 743L, 739L, 751L, 
752L, 750L, 710L, 709L, 708L, 756L, 758L, 2093L, 2094L, 2042L, 
2041L, 2040L, 2029L, 2026L, 2018L, 663L, 665L, 2011L, 2005L, 
1767L, 1766L, 1765L, 1764L, 1763L, 1768L, 297L, 1758L, 1762L, 
1761L, 2352L, 2351L, 1084L, 1085L, 1078L, 1080L, 1079L, 1081L, 
1082L, 1076L, 1077L), c(613L, 1969L, 1981L, 1980L, 1976L, 1972L, 
619L, 617L, 620L, 584L, 585L, 572L, 571L, 570L, 1108L, 1110L, 
1114L, 1115L, 1116L, 1117L, 1132L, 1135L, 1133L, 1134L, 1142L, 
1272L, 1273L, 1248L, 1249L, 1247L, 2507L, 2501L, 2500L, 2509L, 
2514L, 2515L, 1234L, 2490L, 2492L, 2495L, 2487L, 2485L, 1227L, 
2438L, 2437L, 2439L, 2435L, 2449L, 2451L, 2450L, 2447L, 2448L, 
2443L, 2444L, 2442L, 2441L, 2440L, 2483L, 2263L, 2264L, 1204L, 
1225L, 1222L, 1223L, 1220L, 2258L, 2261L, 2260L, 2259L, 2257L, 
906L, 905L, 909L, 910L, 953L, 912L, 949L, 948L, 938L, 916L, 921L, 
974L, 972L, 967L, 983L, 965L, 958L, 960L, 961L, 962L, 964L, 525L, 
527L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 499L, 503L, 523L, 513L, 392L, 393L, 388L, 
389L, 390L, 385L, 380L, 381L, 1811L, 1807L, 368L, 364L, 365L, 
353L, 348L, 1802L, 1785L, 1783L, 1782L, 323L, 321L, 326L, 329L, 
1789L, 1788L, 1787L, 1791L, 1790L, 1792L, 1793L, 1796L, 1794L, 
1773L, 1771L, 1774L, 1775L, 1776L, 1777L, 1780L, 1778L, 1779L, 
1781L, 1770L, 1769L, 2353L, 2356L, 2358L, 2359L, 1760L, 1759L, 
2162L, 2178L, 2179L, 2174L, 2175L, 2173L, 2172L, 2171L, 2169L, 
2167L, 2700L, 2701L, 2698L, 1446L, 2697L, 2702L, 2707L, 2704L, 
2705L, 2706L, 2703L, 2560L, 2561L, 2562L, 2564L, 2576L, 2575L, 
2581L, 2577L, 2572L, 2570L, 2568L, 2569L, 2585L, 2567L, 2598L, 
2597L, 2599L, 2696L, 2355L, 2354L, 1441L, 1034L, 1029L, 1030L, 
1027L, 1028L, 1019L, 1018L, 1023L, 1024L, 1026L, 1025L, 1040L, 
1041L, 1042L, 1007L, 1004L, 1049L, 1002L, 1003L, 2266L), c(610L, 
612L, 608L, 590L, 592L, 591L, 593L, 594L, 595L, 596L, 601L, 604L, 
606L, 607L, 633L, 632L, 631L, 1988L, 1990L, 641L, 642L, 648L, 
649L, 650L, 86L, 68L, 69L, 67L, 66L, 73L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 84L, 
85L, 83L, 88L, 87L, 1580L, 1579L, 1581L, 1582L, 1585L, 1586L, 
1583L, 1584L, 2000L, 1998L, 1617L, 1620L, 1629L, 1626L, 1627L, 
2366L, 2365L, 2384L, 2383L, 2385L, 2371L, 2372L, 2370L, 2369L, 
2364L, 2719L, 2720L, 2726L, 2725L, 2728L, 2727L, 2730L, 2729L, 
2731L, 2732L, 2197L, 2198L, 2194L, 2195L, 2196L, 2193L, 2192L, 
2187L, 2186L, 2185L, 2182L, 2181L, 2180L, 2183L, 2208L, 2209L, 
2200L, 2201L, 2202L, 2199L, 2240L, 2241L, 2252L, 2251L, 2243L, 
2244L, 2249L, 2245L, 2246L, 2247L, 2248L, 2236L, 2235L, 2234L, 
2233L, 2232L, 942L, 932L, 926L, 951L, 952L, 928L, 945L, 2237L, 
2238L, 941L, 939L, 937L, 916L, 921L, 974L, 972L, 967L, 983L, 
965L, 958L, 960L, 961L, 962L, 964L, 525L, 527L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 
493L, 490L, 482L, 480L, 479L, 465L, 459L, 457L, 447L, 456L, 455L, 
454L, 430L, 429L, 428L, 433L, 427L, 426L, 425L, 424L, 423L, 422L, 
421L, 420L, 419L, 418L, 417L, 413L, 414L, 416L, 415L, 412L, 411L, 
410L, 409L, 549L, 550L, 554L, 267L, 1725L, 1744L, 1749L, 1748L, 
1747L, 1750L, 2103L, 2100L, 2118L, 1909L, 1903L, 1860L, 1859L, 
1868L, 1866L, 1882L, 1881L, 1885L, 1886L, 1887L, 1905L, 1907L, 
1910L, 1915L, 2140L, 2161L, 826L, 824L, 724L, 2069L, 2070L, 2063L, 
746L, 748L, 747L, 2081L, 740L, 743L, 739L, 751L, 752L, 750L, 
710L, 709L, 708L, 756L, 758L, 2093L, 2094L, 2042L, 2041L, 2040L, 
2029L, 2026L, 2018L, 662L, 666L, 658L, 659L, 656L, 655L, 654L, 
653L, 652L, 1054L, 1055L, 1056L, 1057L, 1059L, 2323L, 2327L, 
1063L, 2326L, 1064L, 1065L, 1072L, 1071L, 2333L, 2340L, 2315L, 
2314L, 2269L, 2272L, 2307L, 2306L, 2305L, 2290L, 2291L, 2289L, 
2288L, 2283L, 2284L, 2293L, 2292L, 2295L, 2294L, 2299L, 2694L, 
1089L, 1090L, 1443L, 1345L, 1343L, 1344L, 1312L, 1331L, 1314L, 
1313L, 1315L, 1317L, 1322L, 1327L, 1320L, 1321L, 1309L, 1307L, 
1306L, 1305L, 1452L, 1455L, 1454L, 1453L, 1456L, 1451L, 1444L, 
1445L, 1447L, 1450L, 1449L, 845L, 2168L, 2699L, 2348L, 1085L, 
1078L, 1080L, 1079L, 1081L, 1082L, 1076L, 1077L), c(613L, 1969L, 
1981L, 1980L, 1976L, 1972L, 619L, 617L, 620L, 584L, 585L, 572L, 
571L, 570L, 1108L, 1110L, 1114L, 1115L, 1116L, 1117L, 1132L, 
1135L, 1133L, 1134L, 1142L, 1272L, 1273L, 1248L, 1249L, 1247L, 
1250L, 1241L, 1240L, 1213L, 1214L, 1212L, 1211L, 1210L, 1208L, 
1205L, 1207L, 1218L, 1224L, 2480L, 1223L, 1220L, 2258L, 2261L, 
2260L, 2259L, 2257L, 906L, 905L, 909L, 910L, 953L, 912L, 949L, 
948L, 938L, 916L, 921L, 974L, 972L, 967L, 983L, 965L, 958L, 960L, 
961L, 962L, 964L, 525L, 527L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 499L, 503L, 523L, 
513L, 392L, 393L, 387L, 1821L, 1820L, 1809L, 1808L, 1806L, 1805L, 
1804L, 321L, 326L, 329L, 1789L, 1788L, 1787L, 1791L, 1790L, 1792L, 
1793L, 341L, 340L, 338L, 344L, 343L, 342L, 311L, 689L, 690L, 
685L, 684L, 683L, 682L, 680L, 681L, 679L, 678L, 677L, 676L, 668L, 
671L, 673L, 674L, 661L, 662L, 666L, 658L, 659L, 656L, 655L, 654L, 
653L, 652L, 1054L, 1055L, 1056L, 1057L, 1059L, 2323L, 2327L, 
1063L, 2326L, 1064L, 1065L, 1072L, 1071L, 2333L, 2340L, 2315L, 
1002L, 1003L, 2266L))
```

Thank you for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone hits this problem in the future:

This is how "I" solved this problem:

```
library("qualV")

filter_similar_vectors<-function(list_of_vectors,threeshold){
  tic(msg="filter_similar_paths")
  cat(blue(Sys.time(),"-----------< begin filter_similar_vectors ","\n"))
  cat(blue(Sys.time(),"-----------< threeshold: ",threeshold,"\n"))
  
  n <- length(list_of_vectors)
  remove_indices <- c()
  filtered_vectors<-list_of_vectors
  
  for (i in 1:(n-1)) {
    for (j in (i+1):n) {
      q <- LCS(list_of_vectors[[i]], list_of_vectors[[j]])
      if (q$QSI  > threeshold) {
        remove_indices <- c(remove_indices, j)
        break
      }
    }
  }
  if(!is.null(remove_indices))
    filtered_vectors <- list_of_vectors[-remove_indices]
  toc()
  cat(blue(Sys.time(),"-----------< end filter_similar_vectors ","\n"))
  
  return(filtered_vectors)
}
```